# Using global variables in CakePHP Shell scripts

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, constants

Using CakePHP's shell scripts I'm having problems accessing constants, which I normally set within config/bootstrap.php.

Is this because using shell scripts I'm not going through the normal dispatcher routine? What's the best practice for defining constants across shell scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: `define()` works for me. Shells load `bootstrap.php` (see [`ShellDispatcher::__bootstrap()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4c3337598e9355bd866f90c25253b39b908283a3/cake/console/cake.php#L235)).

Answer (score 1):

You can define the constant in app/config/bootstrap.php like this
define("ADMIN_TITLE", "Administrator");